# Problem with hough transformation on python

Tags: python, opencv, hough-transform, convex-hull, canny-operator

I want to apply hough transformation to this image: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rng0.png)

The code that I use is the following:

```
cdst = cv2.cvtColor(hull_img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
lines = cv2.HoughLines(hull_img, 1, np.pi / 180, 200)

a,b,c = lines.shape
for i in range(a):
    rho = lines[i][0][0]
    theta = lines[i][0][1]
    a = math.cos(theta)
    b = math.sin(theta)
    x0, y0 = a*rho, b*rho
    pt1 = ( int(x0+1000*(-b)), int(y0+1000*(a)) )
    pt2 = ( int(x0-1000*(-b)), int(y0-1000*(a)) )
    cv2.line(cdst, pt1, pt2, (0, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
```

(where hull_img [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rng0.png) is the first image that I have attached ).
But the result is : [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReyCF.png)

Why the lines are broken? Why does not find all the lines? Am I doing something wrong? Should I change the code?

If anyone could help me i would be really grateful!
Thank you

Comment: Hough transform finds straight lines in an image. Your image does not have straight lines. They curve a bit, so you get lots of line segments. Try getting the contour after thresholding. Then reduce the number of vertices to 4 using cv2.approxPolyDP(). Then simply draw lines from one vertex to another.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, I followed your advice @fmw42 by adding this part of code before the hough transformation:

```
th3 =cv2.adaptiveThreshold(edged,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(th3, cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
maxArea = 0
best = None
for contour in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
    if area > maxArea :
        maxArea= area
        best = contour

rect = cv2.minAreaRect(best)
box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
box=order_points(box)
coordinates = box.tolist()

perimeter = cv2.arcLength(best,True)
epsilon = 0.01*cv2.arcLength(best,True)
approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(best,epsilon,True)

for cnt in contours:
    hull= cv2.convexHull(cnt)
    hull_img=cv2.drawContours(edged, [hull],0,(255,255,255),5)
```

It seems to improve, but trying it on different types of figures does not totally solve the problem. In some images, the lines found by Hough transformation do not quite follow the contour of the polygon.

Comment: I did not say do a Hough transform. I said simply draw the lines after doing vertex reduction.